# PHP not working in ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: php

yesterday night after working in netbeans and browser for php i closed my laptop and went to sleep. Today morning when i try to work with my projects in browser it is not working i deducted it to be a php problem as it happening in my previous installation and i feared a data breach and reinstalled the OS. And now i see the same problem again.

problems:
when i try to login to my project it is not logging in the same probblem i faced with the previous installation. How do i troubleshoot this problem in ubuntu 18.04.03 as i'm only able to access phpmyadmin only

```
gowri@gowri:~$ php --version
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2019 12:07:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't know whether there's a problem with Ubuntu, NetBeans or your PHP code, so it makes sense to check that your PHP code runs properly in the terminal before you blame your NetBeans project that doesn't work on something else.

The way to troubleshoot a problem with PHP in Ubuntu is with a PHP script named [PsySH](https://psysh.org/) (open source, MIT license). PsySH is a runtime developer console, interactive debugger and REPL for PHP which allows the user to run PHP code interactively from the terminal.

- Auto[Tab][Tab]Complete - PsySH has tab completion for variable names, functions, classes, methods, properties, and even files! Just start typing, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
- Name *all* the spaces - Most PHP shells are terrible at namespaces. PsySH does just what you'd expect.
- Read documentation in context - Have a question about a core PHP function? Try `doc array_map`. Want to read the documentation for an object property? Run `doc $response->statusTexts`.

  ```
  >>> help doc
  ```
- Reflect like a boss - The `list` command knows all about your code — and everyone else's. Easily list and search all variables, constants, classes, interfaces, traits, functions, methods and properties.

  ```
  >>> help list
  ```
- Use the source! - Easily show the source code for any userland object, class, interface, trait, constant, method or property.

  ```
  >>> help show
  ```
- Forget to catch that last exception? - No worries, PsySH has your back. It's available via the `wtf` command.

  ```
  >>> help wtf
  ```
- Learn from your history *and* repeat your past. - Show, search, save and replay your shell history.

  ```
  >>> help history
  ```
- Roll your own commands - If the awesome features listed above aren't enough for you, you can write your own commands. PsySH has first-class support for custom commands — just register them in your `~/.config/psysh/config.php`.

To install PsySH in your home directory run the following commands (`sudo` is not required):

```
wget https://psysh.org/psysh
chmod +x psysh
./psysh
```